# Is there any way to define vector constants that are not be deleted by the function ClearAll?

Tags: variable-definitions

I'm sorry if my question is akward, it's my first question here. :)
I wanna use unit vector of spherical coordinates not using any functions.
(r hat) Cross (theta hat) for example.
Is there a way that I can define vector constants or etc in the system?

Comment: How about `Protect`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no command `ClearAll` that magically clears all defined symbols. `ClearAll` is a function that only affects the symbols you give it as arguments. The `All` suffix doesn't mean all symbols, it means that both values and attributes are cleared, unlike `Clear` which only clears values.

If you don't want some symbols cleared by it, make sure `ClearAll` doesn't see them. If you doing something like

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

then put the symbols you don't want cleared in a different context than `` Global` ``.